# VB.NET - Alternative to "Continue For" for Visual Studio 2003

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

I'm trying to skip to the next entry in a `for` loop.

```
For Each i As Item In Items
    If i = x Then
        Continue For
    End If

    ' Do something
Next
```

In Visual Studio 2008, I can use "Continue For". But in VS Visual Studio 2003, this doesn't exist. Is there an alternative method I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could simply do nothing if your condition is true.

```
For Each i As Item in Items
    If i <> x Then ' If this is FALSE I want it to continue the for loop
         ' Do what I want where
    'Else
        ' Do nothing
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Continue, from what I've read, doesn't exist in VS2003. But you can switch your condition around so it only executes when the condition is not met.

```
For Each i As Item In Items
  If i <> x Then
    ' run code -- facsimile of telling it to continue.
  End If
End For
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not as pretty, but just negate the If.

```
For Each i As Item In Items
    If Not i = x Then 

    ' Do something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why not use [operator <>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GoTo` statement with label at the end of cycle body.

```
For Each i As Item In Items
    If i = x Then GoTo continue
    ' Do somethingNext
    continue:
    Next
```

Comment: I know "goto" statements are unpopular but really this seems to be more of a generic solution than any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill depending on your code but here's an alternative:

```
For Each i As Item In Items
    DoSomethingWithItem(i)
Next

...

Public Sub DoSomethingWithItem(i As Item)
    If i = x Then Exit Sub
    'Code goes here
End Sub
```